# Is it safe to enable logRotate on running server (mongodb)?

Tags: mongodb

I want to enable logRotate on my running server, it reach 4gb at moment. Is it safe to enable at runtime ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/questions/540423/mongodb-proper-way-to-rotate-logs

Refer this answer.

Put this in /etc/logrotate.d/mongod

```
/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 4
    compress
    notifempty
    create
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/pkill -USR1 mongod
        rm /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log.????-??-??T??-??-??
    endscript
}
```